# How to solve Exception Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed?

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-queue

I need help to solve this error Exception Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed

I am using events and listeners.

I wanna save a title, description and a photo. I think , the problem is the photo!

```
    public function storePublication($request){
        event(new  PublicationEvent($request->all()));
    }

    class PublicationEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
    {
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $publication;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($publication)
    {
        $this->publication = $publication;
    }


    class SendAutoResponder implements ShouldQueue
    {   
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  PublicationEvent  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(PublicationEvent $event)
    {
        dd($event);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can’t pass an uploaded file instance to a job (event). You need to write it to disk somewhere, and then retrieve it when handling the job (event). Check [Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed On queue](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/serialization-of-illuminatehttpuploadedfile-is-not-allowed-on-queue)

Comment: If I will delete the photo . Can I pass a title and description? cuz I am doing it.  I can't solve the error!!

Comment: yes you can pass `title` and `description` as parameter.

Comment: instead of passing `$request->all()` are you have a title? then pass `$request->title` and see it will work.

Comment: I guess my answer is solved your problem. then accept my answer. Thanks